# Excel VBA save file automatic to xlsx and delete xlsm -> error 70

Tags: excel, vba

My file.xlsm has some code.
After first time opening it has to save the file to .xlsx and delete the .xlsm

I have the following code:

```vb
Sub OpslaanAls()
  Dim Filenamepath As String, FilenamepathNew as String
    
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  Filenamepath = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
  FilenamepathNew = Replace(Filenamepath, ".xlsm", ".xlsx")

  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ThisWorkbook.SaveAs FilenamepathNew, 51 '51 = xlsx
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

  Kill Filenamepath 'verwijder de xlsm
End Sub
```

The `saveas` part works fine.
But the kill gives me an error 70

why?

Comment: Maybe it can't delete it because the current code is running out of it. Maybe it is still open since code execution is not yet done.

Comment: Try `Filenamepath = ThisWorkbook.FullName` - if ThisWorkbook is not the ActiveWorkbook, the ActiveWorkbook will stay open and cannot be deleted.

Comment: @Ahmad: I was guessing that, but managed to run the code. The VBA code stays visible in the VBE (and can be executed) until you close the workbook - after that it's gone forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try deleting the file from command line, using a batch file

```
Open "batch_file.bat" for output as #1  'create batch file
Print #1, "del " & Filenamepath         'store the delete file command
close #1

Shell "batch_file.bat"  'execute the batch file
```

Comment: It was a permission problem on our citrix server.

problem solved.